# Python - Print when a json object gets higher number

Tags: python, json, for-loop

I want to create a script where I check a json file times to times using a while function. In there there is a json that looks like:

```
    {  
   "names":[  
      {  
         "name":"hello",
         "numbers":0
      },
      {  
         "name":"stack",
         "numbers":1
      },
      {  
         "name":"over",
         "numbers":2
      },
      {  
         "name":"flow",
         "numbers":12
      },
      {  
         "name":"how",
         "numbers":17
      },
      {  
         "name":"are",
         "numbers":11
      },
      {  
         "name":"you",
         "numbers":18
      },
      {  
         "name":"today",
         "numbers":6
      },
      {  
         "name":"merry",
         "numbers":4
      },
      {  
         "name":"x",
         "numbers":1
      },
      {  
         "name":"mass",
         "numbers":0
      },
      {  
         "name":"santa",
         "numbers":4
      },
      {  
         "name":"hohoho",
         "numbers":1
      }
   ]
}
```

and what I want to do is that I want to check every number if numbers for each name has been increased than previous json look.

```
def script():

    with open('data.json') as f:
        old_data = json.load(f)


    while True:
        with open('data.json') as f:
            new_data = json.load(f)

        if old_data < new_data:

            print("Bigger!!" + new_data['name'])
            old_data = new_data

        else:
            randomtime = random.randint(5, 15)
            print("Nothing increased")
            old_data = new_data
            time.sleep(randomtime)
```

Now I know that I have done it wrong and that's the reason I am here. I have no idea at this moment what I can do to make a sort of function where it checks numbers by numbers to see if its gotten bigger or not.

My question is:

How can I make it so it checks object by object to see if the numbers has gotten bigger from previous loop? and if it has not gotten bigger but lower, it should update the value of old_data and loops forever until the *numbers* has gotten bigger than previous loop?

EDIT:

Recommendation that I got from @Karl

```
{
  'names': {
    'hello': 0,
    'stack': 0,
    'over': 2,
    'flow': 12,
    'how': 17,
    'are': 11,
    'you': 18,
    'today': 6,
    'merry': 4,
    'x': 1,
    'mass': 0,
    'santa': 4,
    'hohoho': 1
  }
}
```

Comment: I checked your .json and it appears it has been formatted incorrectly. This is the error indicating the error.  Error: Parse error on line 54:
...ers": 1
    }
    }
  ],
  "total_nu
---------------------^
Expecting ',', ']', got '}'                                                                                                                   Use this link to verify that your .json is correct: https://jsoneditoronline.org

Comment: can't you check just size of the file changing ?

Comment: @VictorS I have now changed it! Should be good now :) Thanks!

Comment: @PIG Well, It is not really what I wanted to do to be honest. But I understand what you mean but I would rather do that without doing any check than just opening the json itself file into the python.

Comment: I would really change your json input to be in a different format. A list of objects is not particulary useful here. It would be much better like this: `{"hello":10, "stack":1, "over":2, ... "hohoho":1}`

Comment: Sure, You can also do that if that is fine! @Karl If you want to give it a try of course I would apprecaite that!

Comment: @Karl I have now updated the thread but I have no idea how I can continue from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your json is in this format:

```
{
  "names": {
    "hello": 0,
    "stack": 1,
    "over": 2,
    "flow": 13,
    "how": 17,
    "are": 12,
    "you": 18,
    "today": 6,
    "merry": 4,
    "x": 1,
    "mass": 0,
    "santa": 4,
    "hohoho": 1
  }
}
```

I would do something along the following lines:

```
import json
import time

with open("data.json") as f:
    old_data = json.load(f)["names"]


while True:
    with open("data.json") as f:
        new_data = json.load(f)["names"]

    for name, number in new_data.items():
        if number > old_data[name]:
            print("Entry '{0}' has increased from {1} to {2}".format(name, old_data[name], number))

    old_data = new_data

    print("sleeping for 5 seconds")
    time.sleep(5)
```

EDIT to answer question posted in comment "just curious, lets say if I want to add another value beside the numbers etc "stack": 1, yes (Yes and no to each of format), What would be needed to do in that case? (Just a script that I want to develop from this)".

In that case you should design your json input as follows:

```
{
  "names": {
    "hello": {
      "number": 0,
      "status": true
    },
    "stack": {
      "number": 1,
      "status": true
    },
    "over": {
      "number": 2,
      "status": false
    },
    ...  
  }
}
```

You would need to change the lookups in the comparison script as follows:

```
for name, values in new_data.items():
    if values["number"] > old_data[name]["number"]
```

(Note that for `status` you could also just have `"yes"` or `"no"` as inputs, but using booleans is must more useful when you have to represent a binary choice like this).

By the way, unless you aim to have objects other than `names` in this json, you can leave out that level and just make it:

```
{
  "hello": {
    "number": 0,
    "status": true
  },
  "stack": {
    "number": 1,
    "status": true
  },
  "over": {
    "number": 2,
    "status": false
  },
  ...
}
```

In that case, replace `old_data = json.load(f)["names"]` with `old_data = json.load(f)` and `new_data= json.load(f)["names"]` with `new_data= json.load(f)`

Comment: Woah, I think this is, This seem to be alot easier with using dicts? Can it be that easy?

Comment: I don't see why it should be more difficult. If you think about it, it really is a fairly simple lookup and compare. Even with your initially suggested JSON structure something very similar (although a bit more cumbersome) could be written.

Comment: It is, I think its more that I just overcomplicated myself I believe. Just curious, lets say if I want to add another value beside the numbers etc `"stack": 1, yes` (Yes and no to each of format), What would be needed to do in that case? (Just a script that I want to develop from this)

Comment: @VictorS Yes Victor. Seems to work as I wanted to :)

Comment: @Hellosiroverthere I've updated my answer to explain how to deal with having a slightly more complicated dictionary structure

Comment: @Karl Woah! That seem alot complicated now! What I did and I am not sure if this is a good idea, however I did a tuple etc `'Hello': (123, 'Kyung'),` where I just looped number[0] as you did from the beginning of the code, Would that be something good to do?

Comment: JSON does not support tuples. If this is what you want to do you could make a list instead: `'heloo': [123, 'Kyung']`. It isn't really that much more complicated though. This is how dictionaries work. You are able to access objects multiple levels down with simple lookup commandas

Answer (score 1):

I took your original .json which you edited and presented in your question and re-factored your code to the below example. It appears to be working.

```
import time
import random
import json

path_to_file = r"C:\path\to\.json"
def script():
    with open(path_to_file) as f:
        d = json.load(f)
    old_data = 0
    for a_list in d.values():
        for i in a_list:
            print()
            for d_keys, d_values in i.items():
                print(d_keys, d_values)
                if type(d_values) == int and d_values > old_data:
                    print("Bigger!!" + i['name'])
                    old_data = d_values
                elif type(d_values) == int and d_values < old_data:
                    print("Nothing increased")
                    old_data = d_values
                    randomtime = random.randint(5, 15)
                    time.sleep(randomtime)   
script()
```

This is the output I receive:

> name hello numbers 0
>
> name stack numbers 1 Bigger!!stack
>
> name over numbers 2 Bigger!!over
>
> name flow numbers 12 Bigger!!flow
>
> name how numbers 17 Bigger!!how
>
> name are numbers 11 Nothing increased
>
> name you numbers 18 Bigger!!you
>
> name today numbers 6 Nothing increased
>
> name merry numbers 4 Nothing increased
>
> name x numbers 1 Nothing increased
>
> name mass numbers 0 Nothing increased
>
> name santa numbers 4 Bigger!!santa
>
> name hohoho numbers 1 Nothing increased

Comment: Hmm so I tried this code and it kinda serems to work but it did say Bigger!! even though it nothing was changed. and I also got hit with `for i in a_list:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable` would a dict be better?

Comment: I also think the problem could be that it says Bigger!! is due to old_data. I think what is needed is to maybe update the value if a value has changed. Etc if `'you': 18,` has changed to 'you': 20,` - then we print out that it has gotten bigger and update the json value so `you` is 20 instead of 18`

Comment: Is this what you are looking to do?

Comment: Well kinda! The thing is that I would like to have it in a loop meaning that in first loop it could say that but in the second loop it should only print if the number has gotten bigger than previous check.